# How to attach to a windows service before it starts?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I need to debug the initialization of a Windows Service. I have a method that is called during the service initialization but since this occurs when it starts I have no enough time to attach the process using Visual Studio. Moreover since the service is not started it no appears in the "attach process" window dialog of VS2010.

So what I need is to debug the service by attaching to it process prior its started.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or config setting to toggle debugging and try the following:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (Settings.Default.DebugApplication)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    }
    // the rest of the code goes here
}
```